# c++ optional/default argument

Tags: c++, function-declaration

I have defined a method with an optional/defaulted last argument called `noAutoResolve` as follows:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<IMessage> TMessagePtr;

class NetworkService : public IConnectionManagerDelegate, public net::IStreamDelegate
{    
public:   
    void send_message(std::string identity, msg::TMessagePtr msg, QObject* window, std::function<void(int, std::shared_ptr<msg::IMessage> msg)> fn, bool noAutoResolve = false);
}
```

and later:

```
void NetworkService::send_message(std::string endpoint, msg::TMessagePtr msg, QObject* window, std::function<void(int res, std::shared_ptr<msg::IMessage> msg)> fn, bool noAutoResolve)
{
}
```

The linker is now unhappy about unresolved externals in the following line where I intentionally omitted the last argument:

```
service_->send_message(endpoint_, msg, this, [this](int result, msg::TMessagePtr msg){
        // .....

    });
```

Is that not possible in c++?

> Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  QTServer    QTServer.exe    1
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall NetworkService::send_message(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,class std::shared_ptr,class QObject *,class std::function)>)" (?send_message@NetworkService@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@UIMessage@msg@@@3@PAVQObject@@V?$function@$$A6AXHV?$shared_ptr@UIMessage@msg@@@std@@@Z@3@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall QTWindow::ExecuteCommand(void)" (?ExecuteCommand@QTWindow@@QAEXXZ)    QTServer    QTWindow.obj    1

Comment: Define "unhappy". Does it complain with an error, and if so, which error?

Comment: If you're sure the *linker* and not the *compiler* is unhappy, then you probably forgot to link in the definition of the function (.cpp). But don't hesitate to post the actual error message :)

Comment: Are you saying the linker is happy when you don't omit the last argument?

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: @baddger964 That's a lambda, note the close parenthesis at the bottom.

Comment: So Just a debugging tip here. It's probable that one of your arguments is somehow wrong try removing arguments and seeing if it links. Use that to narrow down exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @stijn, Yes when I don't omit the last argument in the function call, it does compile and link successfully.

Comment: The problem is not in what you showed here. Please create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I agree with @SanderDeDycker.. probably the problem is not in send_message ( I will suggest to clean that up a bit so your coding would be less error prone. talking about namespace and var names, use your typedefs etc... ). The LNK2019 is the equivalent of "undefine reference" so I would suggest to look for a method declared but not implemented. It is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `fn` parameter of your function is type of `std::function<void(int, std::shared_ptr<msg::IMessage> msg)>`. However, the lambda you are passing is:

```
 [this](int result, msg::TMessagePtr msg){
     // .....
 }
```

This function has the signature of `void(int, msg::TMessagePtr)`, so if there is no conversion from `std::shared_ptr<msg::IMessage>` to `msg::TMessagePtr`, the code cannot compile.

Your problem is therefore not about the optional parameter. For a quick fix, if you have access to a C++14 compiler, try getting the lambda parameters as `auto`:

```
 [this](auto result, auto msg){
     // .....
 }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your post. I actually forgot to mention that I'm using the following typedef:  `typedef std::shared_ptr<IMessage> TMessagePtr;`. Like said, before adding the last argument, everything was working fine even with the lambda I provided. Sorry for not mentioning

Comment: @user66875, oh, okay then.

Comment: I was thinking the same but then I thought that probably that TMessagePtr is a typedef for the shared pointer